# Creating a horizontal layout similar to WPF's WrapPanel (Webdesign)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to represent news for a news website horizontallly, rather than vertically. When someone opens the page, they should see several articles, and instead of scrolling down, the list of articles should scroll to the left or right. This should look quite cool on tablets as it gives you the feeling as if you're scrolling trough pictures, it also has the feeling of the news reader app that's seen in Windows 8. (e.g: http://blog.jasedigitalmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Windows-8-Metro-News-Reader-550x413.png)

My news articles have a set width, but the height can vary depending on the length of the post. I want them to align down, when they reach the end of their parent div, they should wrap to the right and continue from there, this is very much the same behavior as the **WPF WrapPanel** with its orientation set to vertical.

This is what I have now (the boxes have a blue background to make it easier to see the bounds)

[Current Version http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/6629/27149541.png](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/6629/27149541.png)

This is what I'd want (Photoshop mock-up based on above image):

[Future Version http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/4974/41526451.png](http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/4974/41526451.png)

To recap and clear things up, here's my code

### My HTML Layout & Code

- div#wrap: takes the complete width of my browser window
- div#newswrap: inside #wrap, very large width to host my news items, horizontal scroll bar
- div.post: a single post, with fixed width

  ```
  <div id="wrap">
  <div id="newswrap">
     <div class="post">
      <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</div>
      <div class="postcontent"><p>Lorem ipsum *text text*</p></div>
     </div>

     <div class="post">
      <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</div>
      <div class="postcontent"><p>Lorem ipsum *text text*</p></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  ```

And CSS:

```
    #wrap
    {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    }

    #newswrap
    {
    width:2500px;
    height:500px;
    }


    .post
    {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    background: rgba(0,0,120,0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 30px 0px 30px 30px; 
    }
```

I tried to use display:inline-block but it didn't work either. Looks pretty easy but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Question**
Can I capture the scroll event with jQuery/JS so the newswrap scrolls when I scroll down? I tried using the $("#").mousewheel function but it didn't seem to scroll (though it did trigger the event when tested with an alert)

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this,

```
    #wrap
{
width:100%;
height:500px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
overflow:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

#newswrap
{
width:2500px;
height:500px;
text-align: center;
}


.post
{
width: 300px;
/* display:inline-block; */
background: rgba(0,0,120,0.5);
padding: 10px;
margin: 30px 0px 30px 30px; 
}
```

This should do the trick, to clear the extra spaced caused by display: inline-block, then make sure the whitespace between each .post in your html is eliminated.

Comment: Then everything gets aligned vertically, try adding more .post 's to the HTML and you'll see it.

Comment: Try adding vertical-align: middle, and instead of inline-block, change it to table-cell might work.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 features you can use columns ( http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html ) and use `column-break-inside: avoid;` for each element to keep them in blocks. (You'll need the browser specific defines for these CSS properties.) However this won't work in older browsers.

Comment: check the feature support list browser wise at caniuse.com